# Can't access element of JS object

Tags: javascript

This may be the dumbest question in the world, but somehow I'm not being able to access the element `Customer Support` in this object, it returns `undefined`

This is my object:

```
obj = {
    "channel_ids": {
        "IT": 258403,
        "HR": 258404,
        "Design": 258409,
        "Marketing": 258398,
        "Sales": 258413,
        "Writing": 258414,
        "️Customer Support": 258399,
        "Education": 260535,
        "Finance": 258406,
        "Executive": 258407,
        "Admin Assistant": 260554,
        "Social Media": 258405,
        "Legal": 258415
    }
}
```

When I do, for example, obj.channel_ids['Social Media'], it works, obviously
[image]

But when I do obj.channel_ids['Customer Support'], it doesn't, and I have no idea why
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: well I just did obj.channel_ids["️Customer Support"] and it worked fine, so what is different?

Comment: Your first quotation mark for Customer Support is specifically whats causing the issue. Replace that character and it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a hidden character (hex `fe0f`) in your object *definition* above, right after the quotation mark. When I copy your object definition I can't access Customer Support, but when I erase and re-type that property manually I can.

Comment: Same thing happened to me

Comment: specifically, hex `fe0f`

Comment: @StepUp you can use a tool like [this one](https://codebeautify.org/string-hex-converter) to observe the string more closely. The hidden character is right after the quotation mark

Comment: Thanks! How did you find it? I don't know how to make sense of what that tool produces, just a bunch of hex characters. When converting back to string using [this](https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter/cb42717e), the string has a lot of weird characters so not really helpful

Comment: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html, this converter gives a better visual in that it puts spaces between the hex values. if you copy your `"️Customer Support"` you should notice right away that "one of these things is not like the others"...  if you google that `fe0f` value, you'll see it is a "nonspacing mark"

Answer (score 0):

Compared your reference to the object that worked versus manually typing it out in sublime and found a hidden character pre-pended to the "Customer Support" variable.

[Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQGzi.png)